# convert GPS coordinates to SRID coordinates in spatialite

Tags: spatialite

The following query fails for me:

```
select account_nu, srid(geometry), AsText(Geometry) 
from tbl 
where contains(geometry,MakePoint('35.16604','-101.8635',4326));
```

I would like to find shapes that contain a specific point.  All of my shapes are stored under srid 6678.  I assumed the GPS coordinates are stored as 4326, but that's not the case.

How do I convert GPS coordinates to coordinates that I can use in spatial lite?

Comment: For SpatiaLite x means longitude and y latitude. Point ('35.16604','-101.8635',4326)) does not exist because latitude can't be -101 degrees.

Comment: Thank you! after reversing the coordinates everything in the table is returned. Any suggestions on what else I should change?

Answer (score 1):

If the geometry of your "tbl" is in EPSG 6678, then you'll have to do a transform to EPSG 4326 in order to use any spatial comparison. So (continuing from the comment above):

```
select account_nu, srid(geometry), AsText(Geometry) 
from tbl 
where contains(ST_Transform(geometry, 4326),MakePoint(-101.8635, 35.16604,4326));
```